# How to validate hostname in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, hostname

I need to come up with a regular expression to validate hostname against 
[RFC-1123](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt) and [RFC-952](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc952.txt).

Right now I'm using this:

```
^(?=.{1,255}$)[0-9A-Za-z](?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]|\b-){0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z](?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]|\b-){0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?)*\.?$/
```

but this does not do the trick since it does not catch `a.` as invalid hostname.

How do I enhance the reg expression to comply with those RFCs?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Common/lib/Regexp/Common.pm) contains a [regex](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Common/lib/Regexp/Common/net.pm#$RE%7bnet%7d%7bdomain%7d) that matches against [RFC-1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt), is this good enough?

Answer (score 6):

I found [Data::Validate::Domain](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Validate::Domain) on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=RFC+1123&mode=all).

I have not tried this, but it looks promising (has positive reviews etc.).